# How can I configure branch io link to redirect user to a url and never on installed app or playstore

Tags: android, ios, branch.io

I am using branch.io as a url shortener.

This url then gets redirected to another hosted url on a webserver. The page on url shows some customized info based on the data embedded in the shortened url.

Now if the app is installed and user clicks on the link, the user opens a screen in app. How can I avoid that? I want the user to remain on browser after clicking the link.

Answer (score 3):

The default Branch link behavior is as follows:

**1. If the App is not installed:**
Clicking on a Branch link will open the `$android_url` or `$ios_url` (based on the platform) provided in the link. If instead the `$fallback_url` is provided in the link it will open the fallback URL.

**1. If the App is installed:**
On Android, if you have URI schemes correctly configured clicking the Branch link will open your Android App
On iOS, if you have Universal links correctly configured, clicking the Branch link will open your iOS App.

If you want to override this behavior and instead always open the `$android/ios_url` or `$fallback_url` you can do so by making your links web only. You can make a link web only by adding the parameter **`$web_only:true`** to the links. To learn more, check out the documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#open-web-instead-of-app) and [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#redirections)

Answer (score 1):

To add on what Amruta has mentioned, you need to set that in your linkProperties object.

linkProperties..addControlParameter("$android_url", fallbackUrl)

Comment: please consider elaborating on your answer and using the code notation for your code